# one liner erase word "id" from first column tab delimited file

Tags: linux, awk

I have a 10 column tab delimited file, and I would like to erase the word `"id"` from all the entries in the first column of the file.

Is there an awk (or other linux command line) one liner to do that?

I.e., myfile.withid.txt

```
id1 1 2 id3 4 5 6 7 8 9
id2 10 20 id30 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

etc.

with awk to, myfile.woid.txt

```
1 1 2 id3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 10 20 id30 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

etc.

Note that the word `"id"` was erased from the first column.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [unix.se].

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Isn't [tag:awk] a *programming* language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `awk`

```
awk '/^id/ {$0=substr($0,3)}1' file
1 1 2 id3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 10 20 id30 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

Answer (score 3):

this awk one-liner would do:

```
awk -F'\t' '{gsub(/id/,"",$1);print}' file
```

Comment: I just realized the output from this solution does not produce a tab delimited file back... otherwise has no issue.

Comment: @user2805568 you do `awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '....' file` to get TAB delimited output. you mentioned `I would like to erase the word "id" `, but didn't explicitly say the `id` would show only once in 1st column, and it should always be the beginning of the 1st field. that's why I used `gsub(/id/,"",$1)`, e.g. it could be `3id0id xx xx` of course the text like `id33 xx xx ..` would work too

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`awk '{sub (/^id/, "", $0)}{print}' myfile.woid.txt`

For see more detail: `man awk` or http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?awk

Comment: This can be shorten some: `awk '{sub(/^id/,x,$0)}1'`

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate solution:**

```
 awk 'BEGIN{j=1}{$1=j++; print}'>myfile.woid.txt myfile.wid.txt
```

Comment: how do you know the first column is a sequence number?

Comment: @Imagination, just the imagination.